# Current in a generator

Tags: electricity, electric-fields, electromagnetic-induction

According to the Faraday law, voltage will be induced in the generator when the the loop will move in a magnetic field. This voltage will cause the current in the circuit.

My question is

Do charges flow in the segments $a-b$ and $c-d$ of the loop also, or do these segments just give the voltage and then the charges just start to flow in the circuit from the terminals of the loop?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the charges will flow in all of the circuit. If it wasn't so, the circuit would be open and so no charges would flow.